# CSS nesting gives unexpected results

Tags: css, nested

I thought I knew CSS until today. How come the following CSS style give that result?

Stylesheet:

```
li.item a:first-child {color: red}
```

HTML List:

`<ul class="mylist">
        <li class="item"><a href="#">item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li class"child"><a href="#">child item 1</li>
                <li class="child"><a href="#">child item 1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>`

This makes the first two 's red. The `<a>` within `<li class="child">` is NOT the `a:first-child` within `<li class="item">`, how come it's still colored red?
What's an alternative way to target only the first `<a>` within `<li class="item">` without changing the HTML?

How can I target only the first  within li.item?

Comment: First-child refers to any elements that are the first-child of a parent element. It's applying the red color to both LIs because they are both first-child elements to the parent LI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are styling all `a:first-child` elements, which include the ones nesteded further down.

If you want just the top level a element, do this instead:

```
li.item > a {color: red}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aq2NP/1)

The `>` means an `a` tag immediately inside of an `li.item` tag.

Comment: This solved my problem AND gave me a better understanding of the syntax. Many thanks

Comment: No problem. `>` is really powerful. Also look into `+` and `~` selectors

Answer (score 1):

You just have to understand what exactly is happening when you write that selector.

```
li.item a:first-child {color: red}
```

In the above snippet, you're selecting **all** `a` elements that are the first children of that item. If you think about it, the first `a` in the second `li` fits the criteria, it is the first `a` element in its own list.

If you want to specifically select only the direct child, you can use `>` to indicate so:

```
li.item > a:first-child {color: red}
```

This is illustrated in the jsFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/N9B8x/1/